# Query to fetch more rows to append to currently fetched rows using time() function timestamp. MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my current query to fetch the last 10 rows that were added into the table based on the time.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bracket ORDER BY bracket_time DESC LIMIT 10");
```

And I want my site to load more data when the user scrolls down (10 extra rows). So I've been thinking of a query that I could do, that would load more rows to append to the currently loaded rows. But the only solution I've been able to come up with is doing something like this, but I don't know if that's the best way to go about it:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bracket WHERE bracket_time < '$_GET['last_bracket_time']' ORDER BY bracket_time  DESC LIMIT 10");
```

I was wondering if there was another way to go about it? Also here's a picture of my table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6N8N.png

PS: The second query might have syntax errors I just made it as an example, I'm still learning mysql queries so don't mind any syntax. Thanks.

PPS: Should I maybe make another field that auto increments for each row added and use that for my queries?

Answer (score 0):

you will need javascrit or jquery for this, if you want to know that how  to paging in mysql than it can done with limit keyword

ex

```
SELECT * FROM bracket ORDER BY bracket_time DESC LIMIT 10,20
```

Comment: I know. I'm going to be using doing an ajax request. What if the user scrolled down more, wouldn't this load up to only 20 rows?